# How to order data in oracle select query without using order by

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-order-by

I am pretty new to Oracle and came across this question during an interview, which I cannot answer

Display the data in order without using ORDER BY, both ASCENDING and DESCENDING.

Is there any way to do this in Oracle ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Under some circumstances you don't need an `ORDER BY` clause.

Let's say you have table `EMP` with an index on column `EMP_ID`.
Such query does not require an `ORDER BY` clause the result will be ordered automatically by `EMP_ID`:

```
SELECT *
FROM EMP
WHERE EMP_ID > 10;
```

However, **you should not rely on that.** In some conditions Oracle may behave different.

Comment: To quote Tom Kyte, ["reading data out via an index - *does not imply data is sorted by the index key*"](http://tkyte.blogspot.co.uk/2005/08/order-in-court.html). So it might work sometimes, but even with your caveat, I think saying you ever don't need an order-by is dodgy. In some circumstances you might get away without one, until the optimiser does something you don't expect. (But as an interview answer I guess it's OK - as long as the caveat is also supplied)